# Why does TestInitialize execution get included in the test run time?

Tags: c#, performance, unit-testing

I am looking at the performance of my unit tests, and it appears that TestInitialize is included in the overall time it takes for a test to run. This does *not* seem to be the case for ClassInitialize...
Why is TestInitialize's execution time being included in the overall test run time for each individual TestMethod?

Comment: because...it's part of the test execution?

Comment: My point is... I would think the only time that would be included in the test execution is everything marked by the "TestMethod" attribute. My point is re-enforced by the fact that ClassInitialize logic IS NOT included in the time, while TestInitialize *is*. Is this by design? or a mistake that should be fixed in a future version of VS Unit Tests?

Comment: It's by design. `Avg Test Time includes time taken by all the steps executing a test, so that includes the TestInitialize.` [Are TestInitialize method's response time added in Test response time?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf8e458f-9d4d-413d-95ca-97dcbbf02be8/are-testinitialize-methods-response-time-added-in-test-response-time?forum=vstswebtest)